# How to check if a number is a power of 2 in SWIFT

Tags: swift

I find out a lot of example to solve it, but nothing in SWIFT. Please help

smthng like this

Input : n = 4
Output : Yes
2^2 = 4

Input : n = 7
Output : No

Input : n = 32
Output : Yes
2^5 = 32

I needed algorithm for checking if a number is a power of 2. like 4, 8, 16 , 32 , 64 .... is number power of two

Comment: Question title says power of 2 (`2^n`), but body says square of number (`n^2`). So, what exactly do you need?

Comment: I needed algorithm for checking if a number is a power of 2. like 4, 8, 16 , 32 , 64 .... is number power of two

Comment: That's [power of two](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_two), not `pow(n, 2)`.

Comment: sorry have mistake .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Determining if an integer is a power of 2](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#DetermineIfPowerOf2)
from the [Bit Twiddling Hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html)
is almost verbatim translated to Swift:

```
func isPowerOfTwo(_ n: Int) -> Bool {
    return (n > 0) && (n & (n - 1) == 0)
}
```

Example:

```
print(isPowerOfTwo(4))  // true
print(isPowerOfTwo(5))  // false
```

Or as a *generic function,* so that it can be used with all binary
integer types:

```
func isPowerOfTwo<T: BinaryInteger> (_ n: T) -> Bool {
    return (n > 0) && (n & (n - 1) == 0)
}
```

Example:

```
print(isPowerOfTwo(Int16(4)))  // true
print(isPowerOfTwo(UInt8(5)))  // false
```

Or as a *protocol extension:*

```
extension BinaryInteger {
    var isPowerOfTwo: Bool {
        return (self > 0) && (self & (self - 1) == 0)
    }
}
```

Example:

```
print(1048576.isPowerOfTwo)  // true
print(Int(50).isPowerOfTwo)  // false
```

Comment: Oh, why not just declare `n` in `isPowerOfTwo` as `UInt`?

Comment: @user28434: Restriction removed. – I prefer `Int` as argument because that is what most functions in the Swift standard library use (even if the range is restricted to non-negative values)

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer:

If it's a [FixedWidthInteger](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/fixedwidthinteger) and it's positive and its [non zero bit count](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/fixedwidthinteger/2885911-nonzerobitcount) is 1, then it is a power of 2.

```
let x = 128
if x > 0 && x.nonzeroBitCount == 1
{
    // power of 2
}
```

For a floating point number, I think you can just test the [significand](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double/1847553-significand). If it is exactly 1, the number is a power of 2.

```
let x: Double = 4

if x > 0 && x.significand == 1
{
    // Power of 2
}
```

I haven't checked that in a Playground yet, so it might be wrong.

Comment: Isn't it `nonzeroBitCount` with lowercase `zero`? Also works only for positive `FixedWidthInteger`. [Sign bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_bit) is counted in `nonzeroBitCount` too. Negatives have inversed result.

Comment: Yes to both.I'll amend accordingly

Comment: @MartinR, oh, yep, unless `n` is `Imaginary`.

Comment: @user28434 I think you'd have to admit all complex numbers. .

Comment: @JeremyP, `Real` is subset of `Complex`, and for all `Real` n, 2^n will be positive, so you need to look only for `Complex`, excluding `Real`, or `Complex` having non-zero `imaginary` part.

Comment: @user28434 My point was that you need more than imaginary numbers (which are complex numbers with a zero real component) if you want to find the log base 2 of a negative number.

Answer (score -2):

```
let numberToBeChecked = 4

result = numberToBeChecked.squareRoot()

If result%1 == 0 {
    print(“4 is a power of 2”) } else {
    print(“4 is not a power of 2”)
}

//note: result%1== 0 checks if result is a whole number.
```

Hope this works.

Comment: 8 is a power of 2 but its square root is not a whole number. 9 is not a power of 2 but its square root is a whole number.

Comment: Sorry, how is 8 a power of 2? 2^2 = 4, 3^2=9. I understood the question is asking to be able to check if a number is a result of ^2.

Comment: 8 is 2 x 2 x 2 i.e. 2^3. You have confused "power of 2" and perfect square.

Comment: Actually, it's possible that the question is also confusing power of 2 and perfect square